# NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-request

Estou tentando fazer um login num aplicativo no objective-c usando RestKit porem quando eu digito o email e a senha ele apresenta o seguinte erro no console:

```
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ffbd0f5f130> { URL: http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 61;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 25 Feb 2015 21:18:57 GMT";
    Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08)";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Request-Id" = "c8c3c7c6-db3b-432d-82bb-c14b882f42a9";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.011115";
    "X-Ua-Compatible" = "chrome=1";
    "X-Xss-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401}
```

Acredito que nao seja minha api pois ja verifiquei ela e esta tudo certo, mais provável que seja em obj-c pois sou novo nessa linguagem.

ESTE É MEU WEBSERVICE

```
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"

static NSString *kServerURL = @"http://localhost:3000";

@interface JVWebService ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) RKObjectManager *restKitObjectManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *adAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postAdAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postUserAttributes;
@end

#define kSuccessStatusCode RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)

@implementation JVWebService

+ (instancetype)sharedService {
    static JVWebService *sharedService = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedService = [[self alloc] init];

        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
        sharedService.restKitObjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kServerURL]];
        [sharedService.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] email]
                                                                                 password:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] password]];
    });
    return sharedService;
}

#pragma mark - User

- (void)getUserForEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_in.json";

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    User *user = [User new];
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] forKey:@"authencity_token"];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:email password:password];
    [self.restKitObjectManager postObject:user path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,
                                                                              RKMappingResult *result){
        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;
        user.password = password;
        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:user];

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setLoggedViaFacebook:NO];

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    /*
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    NSString *path = @"/login.json";

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:email password:password];
    [self.restKitObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,
                                                                              RKMappingResult *result){

        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;
        user.password = password;

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    */
}

- (void)createUser:(User *)user withProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage {
    NSString *path = @"/users.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage)
                                    name:@"user[avatar]"
                                fileName:@"profileImage.jpg"
                                mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)updateUser:(User *)user withProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage {
    NSString *path = @"/users.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authencity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPATCH path:path parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

//        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage)
//                                    name:@"user[avatar]"
//                                fileName:@"profileImage.jpg"
//                                mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:(User *) result.array.firstObject];
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:result.firstObject];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)logout {
    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_out.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager deleteObject:[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] logout];

        if ([[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] isLoggedViaFacebook]) [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] closeFacebookSession];

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}



- (void)sendResetPasswordInstructionsToEmail:(NSString *)email {
    NSString *path = @"/send_lost_password.json";

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : email};

    [self.restKitObjectManager getObject:nil path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Bom, status HTTP 401 é *unauthorized* (não autorizado), que naturalmente significa que seu serviço não está tendo sucesso na autenticação. É preciso verificar se todo o cabeçalho está sendo enviado correto para realizar a autenticação desta forma. Para mais detalhe acredito que seria preciso conhecer o lado do servidor.

Comment: Achei o erro, era apenas um código que faltava no obj-c